# How to detect what mouse key is pressed in C++ SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, mouse

How do I determine which exact mouse button (right, left, middle, etc.) is pressed? I'm using SDL. Here is the code that I have, which says if any mouse button is clicked or not:

```cpp
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
              {
                Mouse_Pressed = event.button.clicks;
              } break;

            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
              {
                Mouse_Pressed = 0;
              } break;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SDL Mouse Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165716/sdl-mouse-click)

Comment: Not really, the answer there uses something I don't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that through the event *button* field.

```
case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            switch ( ev.button.button ) {
                case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT:
                    break;
                case SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT:
                    break;
                case SDL_BUTTON_MIDDLE:
                    break;
                case SDL_BUTTON_X1:
                    break;
                case SDL_BUTTON_X2:
                    break;
            }
```

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent